# Ingresar datos al input mediante Dom

Tags: javascript, dom, input

```
const miInput = document.createElement('input');
miInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
miInput.setAttribute('id', 'caja');
document.body.appendChild(miInput);
console.log(miInput);
```

Necesito ingresar datos a mi INPUT, mediante el DOM, el input lo cree mediante DOM.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo del mismo modo que asignas el `type` y el `id`, seteando el atributo `value`:

```
miInput.setAttribute('value', 'El Valor');
```

Por ejemplo:

```js
const miInput = document.createElement('input');
miInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
miInput.setAttribute('id', 'caja');
miInput.setAttribute('value', 'Valor insertado de forma programática');

document.body.appendChild(miInput);
console.log(miInput.value);
```